# Wrap featured image with original image link

Tags: php, wordpress

I added in **single.php** the following code to preview in top of the post the featured image

`<?php the_post_thumbnail('artist-top-thumb', array('class' => "img-responsive")); ?>`

and now I want to wrap the image with the link of the original image, so when the user clicks on the image the lightbox will show the full image. I looked the half internet but I cant find a solution (or I searched with wrong terms :) )

How can I do that? Is it possible?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

not too sure what you mean by light box but to return the url and open in a new window:

```
<?php
$pic=wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
?>

<a href="<?php echo $pic;?" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $pic;?>"</a>
```